# How can I prevent Windows from deleting a disconnected device after 30 days?

Tags: windows, drivers, device-manager

I have a USB network adapter that requires a particular network configuration. Sometimes it is unplugged for a few months and the settings are lost. It turns out that Windows, via disk cleanup, regularly removes devices that have not been connected for 30 days.

An excerpt from `%Windir%\Inf\setupapi.dev.log`:

```
>>>  [Device and Driver Disk Cleanup Handler]
>>>  Section start YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.FFF
      cmd: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cleanmgr.exe /autoclean /d C:
     set: Searching for not-recently detected devices that may be removed from the system.
     set: Devices will be removed during this pass.
     set: Default missing device timeout period is 30 days.
     set: Device USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX\XXX will be removed.
     set: Device USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX\XXX was removed.
```

I found a scheduled task, `Microsoft\Windows\DiskCleanup\SilentCleanup`, that runs this command, but it doesn't have anything listed under triggers and I don't really want to disable it anyway.

Is there any way to exclude a device from automatic removal or to adjust the threshold? The "Default missing device timeout period is 30 days" message seems to imply that it's possible to set a different value, but I can't find anything. Based on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1cb0ce0-bfe1-4366-85d3-1b385b6db7d7/windows-81-clearing-plugandplay-state-if-device-not-used-for-30-days?forum=wdk), I tried using `SetupDiSetDeviceProperty` to change the `DEVPKEY_Device_LastRemovalDate` property for the device, but that failed with an access denied error (was done as admin and other properties were writeable).

OS is Windows 10 Version 1909 (18393.1316).

Comment: Please post your Operating system and version.

Comment: @Moab Windows 10 Version 1909 (18393.1316)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you Disable or Delete the `Microsoft\Windows\Plug and Play\Plug and Play Cleanup` task on `Taskscheduler`? 
Did you check the execute History of the task?

From my quick query, the 30 days `MAXCLEAN` timeout is hard-coded (reference: [Old devices and driver cleanup (one command) - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/149630-old-devices-driver-cleanup-one-command.html)). 
And, the existence of the task is depend on Windows version (reference: [1234n6: Windows Plug and Play Cleanup](https://blog.1234n6.com/2018/07/windows-plug-and-play-cleanup.html)), and not all Windows have the scheduled task (on my W10 20H2 there isn't), so it is not so necessary and can be disabled in theory.

Comment: The `Plug and Play Cleanup` task doesn't exist on the PC in question (1909). I think disabling the disk cleanup task would stop it, but this PC has a pretty small drive and I'd prefer something less heavy handed. I also don't want other unused devices to build up over time, both in general and to avoid the 256 COM port limit.

Comment: I was sorry that I did not know Disk Cleanup Manager also cleanup the driver files. Your want is to prevent the specified driver from auto clenup. After I read this ( [How to Remove Unused Drivers from Driver Store | Windows OS Hub](http://woshub.com/how-to-remove-unused-drivers-from-driver-store/) ), I found a way to export and import a driver on the system ( [How to Export (Backup) and Restore Device Drivers in Windows 10 and 8.1 | Windows OS Hub](http://woshub.com/how-to-export-drivers-using-powershell-in-windows-8-1-u1/) ). I hope this will help you.